# What is the exception that makes to throw a Task.ThrowIfExceptional?

Tags: c#, exception, task

I have a windows forms app developed with C# and .NET Framework 4.0 running Task.

I'm sorry to ask this question but I don't know where an exception occur. This is the stack trace:

```
One or more errors occurred.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.Plugins.TICAnKorr.DeviceTICAnKorr.StopLive()
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.Plugins.TICAnKorr.VisorTICAnKorrMini.StopRemote()
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.InterfazDispositivos.ICBaseVisor.DesasociarDispositivo()
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.InterfazDispositivos.ControlMosaico.DesasociarTodosLosPaneles()
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.InterfazDispositivos.ControlMosaico.CrearControlSeleccionado(DeviceBase device)
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.InterfazDispositivos.ControlMosaico.icPanelViewer_MouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.InterfazDispositivos.VisorDeMosaico.mousedown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at MyCompany.BasicInterface.Controles_Basicos.ICLabel.lblText_MouseDown(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.Plugins.TICAnKorr.VisorTICAnKorrMini.MensajeEstado()
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.Plugins.TICAnKorr.VisorTICAnKorrMini.m_DispositivoAsociado_NewResult(Object sender)
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.ConexionesDispositivos.NewResultsEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender)
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.ConexionesDispositivos.DeviceBase.OnNewResult()
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.Plugins.TICAnKorr.DeviceTICAnKorr.HiloCaptura()
   at MyCompany.Dispositivos.ConexionesDispositivos.DeviceBase.<StartLive>b__9()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

I think the exception thrown is this:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       at MyCompany.Dispositivos.Plugins.TICAnKorr.VisorTICAnKorrMini.MensajeEstado()
```

What is the real exception?

If this is not the right place to ask this question, please tell me and I delete it.

I'm not asking about what is the meaning of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`, I know it, I'm asking if this the exception that makes the task to throw a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional`.

Comment: Can't you debug the code?

Comment: No, I can't debug it. This is a production log.

Comment: Here's a tip: Deploy PDBs to production and log the full exception ToString. That gives you more information about the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What happens when you execute an action returning a `Task` is that any exceptions get stored in the task's `Task.Exception` property.

When you call `Wait`, the code waits for the task to finish and then re-throws any exceptions that have occurred inside an `AggreagtedException`. So the `ThrowIfExceptional` method is being called after the task has finished to raise any exceptions that have occurred.

So likely the problem is a null reference in whatever code got executed to return the task being waited on. Should be something inside:

```
 MyCompany.Dispositivos.Plugins.TICAnKorr.DeviceTICAnKorr.StopLive()
```

Answer (score 0):

This may happen because some variables in your class are null and it is not being treated either. I know that you said you know the error, but recently I came across this error and my solution was to place the operator '?' in possibly null variables.